# Webpack 5 Auto Import Chunks For Entries

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, webpack-splitchunks

We have a multi page `React` app and the pages are ASP.NET pages that load the single transpiled entrypoints. We've been doing that fine for a while and the transpiled entries keep getting bigger and bigger in size (understandably).

Now we would like to do code splitting to avoid having 1 single big file. I tried `optimization.splitChunks.chunks = 'all'` and webpack split the chunks as expected. The problem I have is I'd need to know which chunks the entrypoints depends on (which I don't since the chunks names seem to be randomly generated) to import using the `script` tags. I've heard plugins like `HtmlWebpackPlugin` could generate the HTML file that has all the dependencies. However, we're using ASP.NET page that's set up to import only the transpiled entrypoint file.

My question is is there a setting in `webpack` that would make the entries to import the chunks they need? Or is there a plugin that could help with that?

Comment: Have you considered using `import()` functions to split chunks instead of using that option?

Comment: That could be a possibility. Let me look into it.

Comment: @minhtuanta I know it's been a while, but did you happen to find a solution to this?

Comment: @MitchTalmadge - I posted the solution we came up with in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but I'm posting the solution we came up with for anyone interested. The solution we came up with has 2 parts.

The first part is to declare the list of entries.

```
entry: {
    file1: './PATH/TO/JSX/FILE1/file.jsx',
    file2: './PATH/TO/JSX/FILE2/file.jsx',
    // more files
}
```

Then the aspx pages just import the transpiled files.

If you have some kinds of convention like jsx files have the same names as the aspx files, you can automatically generate the entries using a library like `node glob`. Something like this `entry: generateEntries()` then

```
function generateEntries() {
    return glob.synx(
        '/**/*.aspx',
        {
            ignore: [
                '/obj/**',
                '/node_modules/**'
            ]
        }
    ).reduce((entries, file) => {
        if (check if there's a jsx file with the same name) {
            entries[file name with not extension] = path to jsx file
        }
        return entries
    }, {})
}
```

The code above is something I came up on the fly though so you'll need to modify it.

The second part is to split the big commonly used libraries into commonly used chunks using the optimization property like this

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: [
            {
                "name": "kendo_scss",
                "chunks": "all",
                "test": "[\\\\/]js[\\\\/]react[\\\\/]css[\\\\/]kendo[\\\\/]kendo.scss"
            },
            // More of these if you have more
        ]
    }
}
```